# Calculate date difference in integer value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two date fields with IDs gp_vdate_from and gp_vdate_to. And I have a hidden div which is populated by a dynamic table. The div gets visible on click of a button after entering date fields. I did something like this to calculate the date difference

```
function parseDate(str) {
var mdy = str.split('-')
return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
return Math.floor((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24))
}

var diff=(daydiff(parseDate($('#gp_vdate_from').val()), parseDate($('#gp_vdate_to').val())));
```

The date entered is in the format 10-2-2012. 
But I am not able to give to get the difference? Can someone point out why?

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not have valid dates. Look at this line:

```
new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1])
```

This is like writing

```
new Date(2012,9,'feb')
```

for 10-feb-2012, which is not valid. [The date constructor takes arguments like this:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ]);
```

Where all the arguments are integers ('feb' is not valid, also you were passing arguments in the wrong order.)

So I think you need to look at your `parseDate` method.

This is all assuming that JQuery doesn't change how the `Date` object works - you may need to check that.

You should use a javascript console like Firebug for firefox to help you debug.

Comment: Ya that may be the case. but in jquery datepicker the date format is date-month-year which is 10-Feb-2011.

Comment: @Cyphon That's nice, but if you want to use `Date`, which is a stock javascript object, you need to give it arguments with the right order and format.

Comment: I have changed the format to 9-2-2012. But still its not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use date.getTime() to check the difference

```
function daydiff(first, second) {
 return Math.floor((second.getTime()-first.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
}
```

please check with Date object create arguments

```
new Date(year,month,day);
```

Comment: `(second.getTime()-first.getTime()) === (second - first)`

Comment: var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
        function parseDate(str) {
            var mdy = str.split('-');
            return new Date(mdy[2],monthNames.indexOf(mdy[1]),mdy[0]);
        }

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/), a small but awesome JS library just for working with dates. It normalises Date objects across browsers and gives all kinds of sugary methods for working with dates :)

Can be used with jQuery too

**EDIT**

date.js makes working with dates less painful, but is not essential, everything you need can be done in pure JS.

Other answerers - Actually, the Date constructor in JavaScript can accept a single string as an argument, which it uses to generate a new Date object.

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pam4m/) based on your example code showing how to calculate number of days between two dates. Have a look and play around and it might be what you need :)

Comment: Is there no other way to find date differnce apart from using date.js?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I really appreciate it. But unfortunately for me none is working. May be because of the datepick I have used. Its getting more painful now. Thanks again. I am not using date.js because I would need to call that from another JS which will be another mess.